# getting captcha image from webpage [android]

Tags: android, http, response, captcha

I'm trying to make an android app that have same function as this page >>http://goo.gl/6pV6Zr

but I cannot make it work to make HttpPost and i cannot get the exact Captcha image.

i'm trying to retrieve the captcha using jsoup.

```
try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

            Element img = doc.select("img[id=siimage]").first();
            String imgChar = img.attr("src");
            captchaUrl = SECURE_IMAGE_URL + imgChar.substring(1);

            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(captchaUrl).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and set the bitmap in ImageView.

```
captchaImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is my HttpPost.

```
try{
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", number));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ct_captcha", captcha));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("do", "send"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apicode", API_CODE));


        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null){

            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseString);
        }


    }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please guide me how to do the right way to ..

1. retrieve the Captcha image on the page.
2. make a post method.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:-

- this - `Element img = doc.select("img[id=siimage]").first();`

with

- this - `Element img = doc.select("img#siimage").first();`